# Laravel tables with foreign keys - Eloquent Relationships?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I got the following 5 Tables:
[image]

The colors represent the foreign keys, and with which table they are connected.

Quick Explanation:

- "users" - contains my users
- "terminals" - contains terminals
- "terminal_rents" - Stores the period a user X has rented a terminal Y
- "payment_methods" - A Terminal Y can accept multiple payment methods (Visa, MasterCard. This only contains an Id and the Description (p.ex "name" => "Visa").
- "rent_payment_values" - Contains a reference on terminal_rents, and on a payment method (payment_id). For this specific payment method on this Terminal Y there is a ID configured "uid"

A few questions:

1. I figured out that all these relationships should be belongsToMany. Is that correct?
2. I've created Models for all of these databases. How do I need to connect them? And do i have to use any of those optional parameters?
3. Is there maybe a better option to realize this without using 5 tables? I tried to do it like this because then you could add new payment_methods for example at any time without breaking anything.

Thank you

Comment: You need to check the documentation for that, did you read how to post new questions?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very general and strictly discouraged on asking here. However, I decided to give you a clue before you move this ahead.

1. This is `belongsTo` and `hasMany` relationship respectively.

2.For `terminal_rents`

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo("App\User"); // or whatever namespace you use
}
public function terminal(){
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Terminal");
}
```

For `user`

```
public function terminalRents(){
     return $this->hasMany("App\TerminalRents");
}
```

3. This is fine.